# How to set font-family for \num to always coincide with surrounding environemnt

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I am trying to set my global options for the `\num{}` output so that it correspond to the same font style of the surrounding text. I am using the `siunitx` package. After reading the package documentation, I attempted the following, to no avail.

```
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-family}
```

What option should I use to obtain font-family uniformity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  detect-all,
  detect-inline-family=math,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  detect-display-math=true
}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily\num{123}}

{\bfseries\num{123}}

{\itshape\num{123}}

{\ttfamily\num{123}}

$\boldmath{\num{123}}$

\[
\mathsf{\num{123}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]